# Can't send mail from ubuntu

Tags: linux, apache2, sendmail

I can't send mail from Ubuntu and when I `cat /var/log/apache2/error.log`
I see the following error:

> sh: 1: /usr/sbin/sendmail: Permission denied

Note :- SElinux is disabled

```
$ stat /usr/sbin/sendmail 

  File: ‘/usr/sbin/sendmail’ -> ‘/etc/alternatives/sendmail’
  Size: 26         Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   symbolic link
Device: 801h/2049d Inode: 1318147     Links: 1
Access: (0777/lrwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
```

Comment: Could you "chase" links to the end? `/usr/sbin/sendmail` is a link to `/etc/alternatives/sendmail`.  `/etc/alternatives/sendmail` is a link to yet another file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be a `superuser` to use any binaries found at `sbin`. As `sendmail` is in `/usr/sbin/`, you have to be `superuser`, If your are not, You will get the `Permission denied` error